# How to filter an array of refs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-ref

I have an array of data that i map over and display on screen. i want to be able to do stuff to these dom elements when clicked. I've stored the refs in an array and now onclick i want to do something with the one that was clicked and something else with the rest.

So i thought of using es6 filter to remove the current one from a new array and then iterate over them. And then i'm free to do whatever i want with the item that was clicked.

However i can't get the filter to work. doesn't console anything.

https://codepen.io/_adamjw3/pen/MWWmGEg

```
class App extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super();
    this.myRefs = [];
    this.state = {
        testData: [
            "dave",
            "pete",
            "mark"
        ]
     }
  }

  myActionHandler = key => {
     const selectedDomElement = this.myRefs[key];
     const filtered =  this.myRefs.filter(item => item !== item);


     filtered.forEach(function(entry) {
        console.log("all but selected ne", entry);
    });
  };

    render(){
        return (
            <div className="container">
                {this.state.testData.map((item, key) => {
                    return (
                        <div key={key} >
                            <button onClick={() => this.myActionHandler(key)} ref={ref => (this.myRefs[key] = ref)} >
                                {item} 
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    );
                })}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like your only issue is that you're filter function is wrong. It should use the `selectedDomElement`.

```
const filtered =  this.myRefs.filter(item => item !== selectedDomElement);
```